# range price in openerp

Tags: odoo

Can I make a price limit or like range price ? so if the prices are beyond the type that has been specified, it will come out a warning. I tried setting in the price list. but still can not

is there a module that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have feature like this .

Please provide 2 fields in product `min_price` and `max_price`

in SOL or POL override the `onchange` events of the product and check for the condition and return warning in case of the conditions .